# JWT Authorization failed with Angular 7 + Spring Boot + h2 database

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

This is the **error** I am getting in **intelliJ** when I call the Angular code from the frontend:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.getAuthentication(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

This is the **chrome console** when I click login:

```
    POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate 403
login.component.ts:32 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/authenticate", ok: false, …}
```

This is the **Angular code** that is getting called when I click login:

```
export const TOKEN = 'token'
export const AUTHENTICATED_USER = 'authenticaterUser'

executeJWTAuthenticationService(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      `${API_URL}/authenticate`, {
        username,
        password
      }).pipe(
        map(
          data => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER, username);
            sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN, `Bearer ${data.token}`);
            return data;
          }
        )
      );
  }
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter** class:

```
    public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter** class:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) {
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}
```

}

**User entity**:

```
    @Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Orders order;

    //getters and setters
```

**User Controller**:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private UserService service;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserController(UserService service, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.service = service;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll() {
        List<User> users = service.getUsers();

        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(
            value = "register",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> registerUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsModel userDetails) {
        userDetails.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDetails.getPassword()));
        service.createUser(userDetails);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**end of code**:
   My main concerns is that the code is working but I am calling the wrong URL. I am currently calling localhost:8080/authenticate and sending the username and password. 
   I can successfully add a user to the database using the register button(checked it in h2 console), but I cannot log in that user.

I am pretty new to JWT, although I have read a lot about it online.

Please hint me to what to do since the code is from an online tutorial and I don't really understand much of it. I just need to make the login to work in order to finish my project.

Also a link to a good online tutorial about implementing JWT authentication would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your token generated? You must generate token with exactly same signature as the one you parse it with.

Comment: @SergVasylchak thanks for pointing it out. I have added the class under JWTAuthorizationFilter class

Comment: In case your secrets in `JWTAuthenticationFilter` and `JWTAuthorizationFilter` are the same I cannot see any trouble in your code. You may try debugging your security flows. Wish you luck and please let know when you discover the problem reason.